# Traversing grid in a snake like pattern

Tags: algorithm, rectangles, cartesian-coordinates

I have a rectangle defined by its four corners on a Cartesian coordinate system.
The rectangle consist of identically sized cells.

Given one of the corner cells as a starting point and a direction (either along x or y axis) how can I traverse this grid in snake like pattern?

For example, here (x4, y4) is the starting cell and direction is defined to be along the x axis. Blue line depicts the desired path.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Well, just go left until you hit a wall. Then go one up. Then go right until you hit a wall. Then go up. Then go left until you hit a wall. Then go one up. Then go right until you hit a wall. Then go up. Then go left until you hit a wall.Then go one up. Then go right until you hit a wall. Then go up. Then go left until you hit a wall.Then go one up. Then go right until you hit a wall. Then go up. Then go left until you hit a wall.Then go one up. Then go right until you hit a wall. Then go up. Then go left until you hit a wall...... get the idea?

Comment: @dingalapadum That's what I've been doing but I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution. 
At the moment the implementation I have is very cumbersome because, well, all the combinations of starting points plus directions simply lead to tons of if/else/for_loops

Comment: i was joking.. But a good start would be to post your code here to see what you tried.. How do you exactly get the input. What should the output look like? As it stands, the question is not so clear..

Comment: The input is simply four pairs of coordinates plus the direction (let's say a boolean: true = follow along x axis, false = follow along y axis)
Output is an array of coordinates along the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the 4 pair of points to find the opposite point that defines the box. Then you have a Start and an Opposite pair of points. In your case, followAlongX will be an input so it's not needed to test the direction but I added a classic decision text otherwise.

In the end, try something like (Java, written in Notepad, not tested):

```
int stepY, stepX, yMin, yMax, yOpposite, yStart, xMin, xMax, xOpposite, xStart;
if (yOpposite > yStart) {
    stepY = 1;
    yMin = yStart;
    yMax = yOpposite;
}
else {
    stepY = -1;
    yMax = yStart;
    yMin = yOpposite;
}

if (xOpposite > xStart) {
    stepX = -1;
    xMin = xStart;
    xMax = xOpposite;
}
else {
    stepX = 1;
    xMin = xOpposite;
    xMax = xStart;
}

// boolean followAlongX = false;
// if (xMax-xMin>yMax-yMin) {
//     loopOnX = true;
// }

List<Points> path = new ArrayList<>();
if (followAlongX) {
    for (int i=yMin; i!=yMax; i+=stepY) {
        for (int j=xmin; j!=xmax; j+=stepX) {
            path.add(new Point(i,j));
        }
        stepX = -stepX;
        int temp = xMin;
        xMin = xMax;
        xMax = temp;
    }
}
else {
    for (int j=xmin; j!=xmax; j+=stepX) {
        for (int i=yMin; i!=yMax; i+=stepY) {
            path.add(new Point(i,j));
        }
        stepY = -stepY;
        int temp = yMin;
        yMin = yMax;
        yMax = temp;
    }
}
return path.toArray(new Point[path.size()]);
```

Comment: You can probably avoid to copy the double loops for both case. To do so 1) delete one of the double loops, 2) remove the test before the remaining double loop, 3) test followAlongX before creating a point, 4) switch (i,j) to (j,i) according to the test results.